# /admin/install/ missing resource files (css/js 404) and is unstyled

Tags: install, nginx

Has anyone else run into an unstyled /admin/install/ page? Inspector shows 404 on all css and js files and they are pointing to /admin/resources/*

Been searching around and it doesn't seem to be a common issue so I'm a bit stumped. (Trying to install on an ubuntu/nginx digitalocean droplet)

I'm currently staring at this screen:
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely an nginx config file issue.  There are some configs that are working for people here: [What is the recommended Nginx configuration for Craft?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/961/what-is-the-recommended-nginx-configuration-for-craft)

Comment: That .conf file worked for me with a minor change in fastcgi_pass value (i'm on ubuntu/digitalocean droplet) to
`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`

Spent the entire day trying to figure this out, and I can finally start migrating my local build over. Thanks Brad, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you have [zlib.output_compression](http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression) enabled. See this help article:

http://buildwithcraft.com/help/missing-cp-css-js

Comment: You'd still get a 200 O.K. in the response. His are actually 404'ing.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I just checked my php.ini and zlib compression is off:

`zlib.output_compression = Off`