# Serving Craft from a sub-directory on Nginx

Tags: install, nginx

I'm starting with a clean install, empty database.

What would be the changes needed to this [Nginx configuration](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/961/what-is-the-recommended-nginx-configuration-for-craft) to serve craft from /articles/ instead of "/"?

Any specific configurations that needs to be done to the Craft configs?

I've tried many combinations that all ended in 404.

Current layout:

/srv/www/app/craft <- "craft files"

/srv/www/webroot <- "public webroot"

/srv/www/webroot/articles/ <- "craft index.php here (with path set correctly to craft)".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just adjust the folder for the webroot set the root to

/srv/www/webroot/articles/

And in the index.php file make sure the path to the craft folder is

'../../app/craft'

UPDATE:

If you instead want to leave the webroot as is and just have craft run from yourdomain.com/articles you would need to also update the index.php to make sure the craft path is set correct

and in the nginx file add this

```
location /articles/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;  
}

location @rewrites {
   rewrite ^/articles/(.*)$ /articles/index.php?p=$1 last;
}
```

put that directly above this line, everything else can be the same

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

Comment: Actually, the purpose of this sub-directory is that I have another app running from the webroot/, I can't point the server root to articles/. (index.php is set to point to ../../app/craft, and I do get 404 pages from Craft, but not much more.

Comment: ok let me update my answer then

Comment: Keith, I think it worked.  Initially I still got the 404, but calling /articles/admin/install fired the install process.   It ended with a Oops page, but nothing alarming in the craft.log, and all looks operational so far.  I will do more testing.

Comment: Once inside the CP, I had to add /articles to the end of the site URL under the General Settings, is this normal or should that have been set automatically during install?

Comment: Yea that's normal.  You can also just site the siteurl in the general.config but craft expects that to be the root of any craft urls it will build