# How to fix admin assets url-s on nginx?

Tags: nginx

After moving a Craft website from Apache server to Nginx, the admin css\js assets url-s stopped resolving.
For example, on /admin/login page Craft CMS tries connecting to the /admin/resources/lib/jquery.min.js - even though that directory structure doesn't exist, it still connects fine on Apache server, but results in a 404 page on nginx.

How are these routes generated? What need to be added to vhosts file in order for it to work?

Note that Craft is used to generate only the part of the website - e.g. www.example.com/craftpages is my Craft homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just sounds like your nginx conf file isn't setup properly.  See [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/961/what-is-the-recommended-nginx-configuration-for-craft) for some working examples.