# Barebones LEMP + Craft CMS walkthrough

Tags: nginx, setup

No fancy deployment, version control etc etc. Just a cut and dry walkthrough on how to get Craft CMS up and running on a LEMP stack, does it exist? I'm fairly new to craft but have had no problem with the more documented LAMP stack but there seems to be a lack of LEMP & specifically nginx directives relating to craft. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't think I've seen a specific step-by-step walkthrough for LEMP, but [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/961/what-is-the-recommended-nginx-configuration-for-craft) is a start for an nginx conf file.

Comment: Thanks @BradBell i'll have a go with that .conf and if I have some luck i'll try my hand at putting together a basic lemp + craft walkthrough.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one: https://medium.com/good-dog/deploying-craft-cms-to-amazon-ec2-running-the-lemp-stack-using-mina-e2ad955138fa#.54s4y29co

Disclaimer: I work for the company that published this.