# How do I get to the web UI in CraftCMS to install it?

Tags: installation

I initially tried this with Ubuntu Linux and a .tar.gz file without the composer tool.  I was using MySQL and PHP 7.4.  My problem is about the same with my second attempt.  I will now describe my second attempt and ask for help with it (instead of my first attempt).

I am trying to install CraftCMS on Debian 10 with composer.  Everything seems to work on the back-end.  I am using PostgreSQL and PHP 7.3.

I finally went to the web front-end portion of the directions.  In a web browser I go to /index.php?p=admin/install

It resolves to /dashboard.  The web page that is rendered says "Not Found   The Requested URL was not found on this server"

When I just go to "" in the web browser, I see "Welcome  Thanks for installing Craft CMS!"  I can click on the "Control Panel", but that takes me to a page that is Not Found.

I expect to see the screen to install CraftCMS in a web browser when I go to /index.php?p=admin/install

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never seen the `/index.php?p=admin/install` url suggested, but maybe things have changed. I always just go to `/admin`, so maybe give that a try?

Comment: And I don't mean to insult your intelligence by asking this, but you aren't just putting `/index.php?p=admin/install` as the entire url are you? You're doing `http://examplesite.com/index.php?p=admin/install` , right?

Answer (score 2):

How exactly are you running Craft?

Ubuntu/Debian are just Linux operating systems, they don't necessarily come with a web server stack installed but it looks like what you're running is at least partially working.

- If you getting the **welcome screen**, it sounds like Craft got installed so I wouldn't try reinstalling unless you can confirm there's no tables for Craft in your database.
- If you can get to `http://examplesite.com/index.php?p=admin/dashboard`, that typically means the web server's rewrites aren't working and what you have now is a webserver configuration issue—not uncommon.

To solve a web server issue:

- **Apache:** make sure `.htaccess` is located inside Craft's web folder and `AllowOveride All` is in your virtual host config.
- **Nginx:** you need some [special rewrite rules](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/961/what-is-the-recommended-nginx-configuration-for-craft) to get it going.
- You may also need to set `omitScriptNameInUrls` to `true` in `config/general.php`.

If you can't get to the dashboard or the login screen, something else happened, perhaps a botched install and you should revisit how your web server got installed.